# How to get first n records of groups based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am wondering how I can use `groupby` and `head` to get the first n values of a group of records, where n is encoded in a column in the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1] * 4 + [2] * 3, "B": list(range(1, 8))})
gp = df.groupby("A").head(2)
print(gp)
```

This will return the first 2 records of each group. How would I go ahead if I wanted the first 1 of group 1, and the first 2 of group 2, as encoded in column `A`?

Desired outcome:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
4  2  5
5  2  6
```

Comment: ``pd.concat([df.groupby("A").get_group(1).head(1), df.groupby("A").get_group(2).head(2)])``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution with [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) in custom function by `A` passed by `x.name` - here is filtered data by `A` values:

```
gp = df.groupby("A", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(x.name))
print(gp)

   A  B
0  1  1
4  2  5
5  2  6
```

If need filter by order in `A` values solution is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [8] * 4 + [6] * 3, "B": list(range(1, 8))})

d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(df.A.unique(), 1)}
gp = df.groupby("A", group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(d[x.name]))
print(gp)

   A  B
0  8  1
4  6  5
5  6  6
```

Answer (score 3):

We can create a sequential counter using `groupby` + `cumcount` to uniquely identify the rows within each group of column `A`, then create a boolean mask to identify the rows where the counter value is less than or equal to value encoded in column `A`, now we can filter the required rows using this boolean mask

```
df[df.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1).le(df['A'])]
```

---

```
   A  B
0  1  1
4  2  5
5  2  6
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df_ = pd.concat([gp[1].head(i+1) for i, gp in enumerate(df.groupby("A"))])
```

```
# print(df_)

   A  B
0  1  1
4  2  5
5  2  6
```